# React Hook Form - Controller : Migrating from v5 to v6

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using React Hook Form v5 and this is the syntax for Controller component:

```
<Controller as={Input}
   name="test"
   onChange={([_, value]) => value}
   onChangeName="onTextChange"
   onBlur={([_, value]) => value}
   onBlurName="onTextChange"
   valueName="textValue"
 />
```

And here is the syntax for Controller in RHF v6:

```
 <Controller name="test"
   render={({ onChange, onBlur, value }) => {
     return <Input
       valueName={value}
       onTextChange={(val) => onChange(value)}
       onTextBlur={(val) => onBlur(value)}
     />
   }}
 />
```

The question is, after upgrading, the old Controller still works and I wish to keep them because there are lots of them in my current code and it would take a huge amount of time to replace all of them. Is there any big risk doing that?

Please give me some advice, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to have a read the changelog.

https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

`Controller` is one of the major changes from v5 to v6.

- we still keep `as` prop, but removed many extra props
- we introduce `render` prop for more customized usage

If everything is working as expected for your project with `as`, I would still suggest removing those props that not been used.

- onChange
- onChangeName
- onBlur
- onBlurName
- valueName